# No holes for ducted hood in kitchen above stove

Tags: kitchens, exhaust-fan, gas-burner, range-hood

I moved into a new apartment. There are no holes made in the cabinets or wall for a duct for a hood above the stove area. I have a large gas stove which I use almost daily.

However, there is an extractor built into the wall which connects to a shaft outside, and pulls a decent amount of air. When I held a balloon to it (no idea if this is significant at all), it held it firmly, so it does feel acceptably powerful. The fan blade itself must be about 9 inches in diameter, and the grill cover has grease on it (whereas the cabinets around the stove are seemingly clean after 2 months of near-daily cooking).

Diagonally, it's about 2 meters away from the stove. The stove cannot be moved due to the design of the kitchen. Is this good enough, and if not, what should I do? I cannot afford to spend thousands of $ right now, and im considering moving next year, but I've got a small child in the house.

Comment: If strong enough to pull grease 2 meters, it should be strong enough to pull the nasties from burning gas.  Just make sure there is enough incoming fresh air to replace what goes out.

Comment: A pic would help us figure out a workaround for you.